# Why does this statement won't work in ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle

The statement I'm trying to execute in ORACLE:

```
update c1 
set c1.valor = x.tot_cap 
from OBM2019.compproj c1 
inner join (
    select chave_projecto, ascendente a, sum(valor) tot_cap 
    from OBM2019.compproj 
    where chave_projecto = '1' 
    group by chave_projecto,ascendente
) x 
on c1.chave_projecto = x.chave_projecto 
where c1.chave_projecto = '1' 
and c1.numero = x.a;
```

Gives error on column 35 "SQL command not properly ended".
Thanks.

Comment: Oracle doesn't support `from` in `update` .

Comment: you need to use `merge`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
update (
   select c1.valor, x.tot_cap 
   from OBM2019.compproj c1 
      inner join (
        select chave_projecto, ascendente a, sum(valor) tot_cap 
        from OBM2019.compproj 
        where chave_projecto = '1' 
        group by chave_projecto,ascendente
      ) x on c1.chave_projecto = x.chave_projecto 
   where c1.chave_projecto = '1' and c1.numero = x.a
   )
SET valor = tot_cap;
```